# Context Menu Shell Extension not working under Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, 64-bit, windows-shell

I created very simple Context Menu using Shell Extension in C#. It works fine under Windows XP 32 bit but under Windows 7 64 bits menu items not appearing.

I tried to build Setup output to x64 but no effect.

Simple Source contains ContextMenu and Setup project is [here](http://www.pawelsmejda.com/TemporaryGarbage/SetupTest.zip).

Looks like Wow6432 should be handled by Setup project, same for registration and adding to Global Assembly Cache

I would be appreciate for help / suggestions with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to strongly recommend you stay away from any code written by Esposito.  As usual, his P/Invoke declarations in the ShellExt folder are completely wrong, they cannot work in 64-bit code.  Publishing this code was very irresponsible in the first place, shell extensions should never use a .NET CLR version before 4.0.  Visit pinvoke.net if you want to rescue it.

Comment: I wrote this in C++ as recommended, no problems at all, thx for usefull advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the DLL's platform in Visual Studio and make sure it's 64-bit. 64-bit processes can't load 32-bit DLLs into their process space (and vice versa, naturally).

To build a 64-bit version of your DLL, use Visual Studio's Configuration Manager to create a new solution platform. Select X64 (instead of X86 or any platform), and rebuild the project. There are also [command-line switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zekwfyz4%28VS.100%29.aspx) for C# compiler, if you are using scripted builds.

Comment: I also tried this but then I have "BadImageFormatException was unhandled", and recomended solution for this is to change build for x86

Comment: What are your references? Do you reference any 32-bit DLLs in your project? That will limit your 64-bit Windows Explorer compatibility.

Comment: I'm using ShellExtension so belive he is using Shell32.dll which is 32-bit DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same problem. You need to change InstallUtil.dll in your setup file. I wrote a article in my blog about it.
http://artyomgrigor.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/register-shell-extension-context-menu-also-on-windows-x64-part-2/